# How do I get a download url after a file is uploaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a backend server using SpringMVC and receive the file upload from user using the below code:

```
String imgPath = FileUtil.transferFile(imageFile);
```

This will generate the absoulte path of the file uploaded of the server into the imgPath. But right now I need to have a public path to that file so that the frontend can download it since we are on two different servers. Something like

```
www.xxx.com/file/img.jpg
```

Could anyone give me some idea what should I do about this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can add static resource handler for the location of the images:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
      .addResourceHandler("/file/**")
      .addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/images");
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But how do I get the URL of the image?

Answer (score 0):

I would give the community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) a try.  This provides an abstraction over storage for handling resources.  It injects the service implementation and controller for you so that you don't need to write either yourself.

Adding it would look something like this:

> pom.xml (assuming maven.  Spring boot starters also available)

```
    <!-- Java API -->
    <!-- just change this depdendency if you want to store somewhere else -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- REST API -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class StoreConfig {

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() throws IOException {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(new File("/path/to/uploaded/files").getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> FileStore.java

```
  @StoreRestResource(path="files")
  public interface FileStore extends Store<String> {
  }
```

And that's it.  The FileStore is essentially a generic Spring ResourceLoader.  The `spring-content-fs`  dependency will cause Spring Content to inject a filesystem-based implementation.  The `spring-content-rest` dependency will cause Spring Content to also inject an implementation if an `@Controller` that forwards HTTP requests onto the methods of the `FileStore` service.

So you will now have a fully functional (POST, PUT, GET, DELETE) REST-based file service at `/files` that will use your `FileStore` to retrieve (and store) files in `/path/to/uploaded/files` on your server.

So:

`curl --upload-file some-image.jpg /files/some-image.jpg`

will upload `some-image.jpg` and store it in `/path/to/uploaded/files` on your server.

And:

`curl /files/some-image.jpg`

will retrieve it again.  In your case this would be the URL you use in your `<img/>` tags.

HTH

The injected controller also supports video streaming too, in case that is useful.

With this you could also remove all of your controller and service code as it is no longer required.  Plus, as Spring Content is an abstraction over storage, in future, you could also shift to any of the other storage mediums supported by Spring Content; S3 for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!